# Jquery Modal Pop Up Redirect

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a popup that will appear when a user clicks on a external link. The user has the option to continue by clicking the button "OK". Otherwise, if the user clicks on "Cancel", the user stays on the page.

I am able to detect when the user clicks on a external link and have the modal to appear fine.

I found an tutorial online on how to create a modal instance using [Jquery](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/). I was able, for the most part, be able to adjust the modal to my liking (although there are some alignment issues).

The issue I am encountering is how to grab the url of the anchor tag that was clicked on to the modal instances created in Jquery.

One approach I thought that would work is to create the buttons outside of the Modal instance and have these buttons appear when I call the Modal to open in my click function (below shows where I am setting my variable to the modal to open when anchor tag is clicked) which also resolve the alignment issues I was encountering mentioned earlier.

```
       var m = modal.open({content: "<div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'>
<h4 class='modal-title'>You are Now Leaving Our Site</h4>
<button id='closex' style='margin:5px' type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button></div>
<div class='modal-body'>" 
+ "<p>You are now exiting the Regal Medical Group, Inc.  (RMG) web site.  When you exit this site to access a different non-RMG web site, you become subject to the other web site’s privacy policy and practices.  To learn about the other web site’s policy and practices, refer to the privacy policy statement posted on the web site’s home page.<br /><br />Press Ok to Continue<br />Press Cancel to Abort</p>" + "<br />" + "<div class='modal-footer'><button id='redirect' class='ok' href='#'>Ok</button><button id='close' class='cancel' href='#'>Cancel</button></div></div></div>"});
```

Then I thought I could create functions where it checks which buttons were clicked. If the "Ok" button was clicked, capture the url, clear the overlay, clear the modal (reason being that some of the links on the site working on have "target="_blank" in the anchor tag) and redirect the user to the desire site. Otherwise, if "Cancel", clear the overlay, clear the modal and remain in the same page.

However, this approach did not work.

My question: How can I get these buttons to work inside the instance of the Modal?

The following is the click functions for all anchor tags (where variable "m" is the modal):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {



$('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),
            host = location.host;

        console.log("URL: " + url + " HOST: " + host);

        if (url.indexOf(host) > -1 || url.indexOf('http','https') == -1){
            /* If we find the host name within the URL,
               OR if we do not find http or https, 
               meaning it is a relative internal link
            */
            window.location.href = url;
        } else {
var m = modal.open({content: "<div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'>
    <h4 class='modal-title'>You are Now Leaving Our Site</h4>
    <button id='closex' style='margin:5px' type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button></div>
    <div class='modal-body'>" 
    + "<p>You are now exiting the Regal Medical Group, Inc.  (RMG) web site.  When you exit this site to access a different non-RMG web site, you become subject to the other web site’s privacy policy and practices.  To learn about the other web site’s policy and practices, refer to the privacy policy statement posted on the web site’s home page.<br /><br />Press Ok to Continue<br />Press Cancel to Abort</p>" + "<br />" + "<div class='modal-footer'><button id='redirect' class='ok' href='#'>Ok</button><button id='close' class='cancel' href='#'>Cancel</button></div></div></div>"});
if(m == true) {
                return m;
            } 
        }
        });

    });
```

and the following code is the instance of the modal:

```
/*Pop-Up Modal Set UP
========================================*/
var modal = (function(){
    var 
    method = {},
    $overlay,
    $modal,
    $content;/*,
    $close,
    $cancel,
    $ok;*/

    // Center the modal in the viewport
    method.center = function () {
        var top;
        var left;

        top = Math.max($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;
        left = Math.max($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;

        $modal.css({
            top:top + $(window).scrollTop(), 
            left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
        });
    };

    // Open the modal
    method.open = function (settings) {
        $content.empty().append(settings.content);

        $modal.css({
            width: settings.width || 'auto', 
            height: settings.height || 'auto'
        });

        method.center();
        $(window).bind('resize.modal', method.center);
        $modal.show();
        $overlay.show();
    };

    // Generate the HTML and add it to the Modal document
    $overlay = $('<div class="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>');
    $modal = $('<div class="modal id="myModal"></div>');
    $content = $('<div class="modal-dialog">');

    $modal.hide();
    $overlay.hide();
    $modal.append($content);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Add the Overlay and Modal
        $('body').append($overlay, $modal); 
    });

    return method;
}());
```

Comment: @mplungjan: can you provide more context. Sorry for asking

Comment: Unless you are using the browser's `confirm()` method to ask the user, you have no means to create a blocking modal -  your modal is just a bunch of new elements on the screen. That means when you trigger the modal you should return a promise. Clicking _OK_ or _Cancel_ should resolve or respectively reject that promise. On caller side you can attach a `then` (and a `catch`) to handle them. Of course, if you can, you should use async/await syntax as it is much clearer. As a working example check UIKit's modal utilities (scroll the page to the end): https://getuikit.com/docs/modal

Comment: @ mplugjan: I tried implementing what you suggested but I am unable to get the url. I just get the site url followed by "/undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nothing is executed after a return
2. you already had an `e.preventDefault();`
3. bind is deprecated for .on

To answer:

Store the URL and use it later

```
var $currentLink;
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $currentLink = $(this); 


...

$(document).on("click","#redirect",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($currentLink) location = $currentLink.attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate it. I see what you mean know

Comment: @ mplugjan: I tried your approach but it forces the user to go to a page that does not exist

Comment: @mplugjan: I can see if the url was pass correctly. Currently, as I see it, shows undefiend

Comment: Ah, the modal is not generated at click time. Ok, I'll change the code

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a complete example for what I understood you need. As you will notice, I am not recreating the dialog each time, just hiding it when not needed. You might also notice the async/await and the array notation syntax. If you need to be bakcward compatible with older browsers they can be easily transcribed or transpiled, but I hope you will better understand it this way.

```js
        
        confirm = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let yes = $('#overlay button#yes')
   let no = $('#overlay button#no')
   
   off = (then) => {
    yes.off() 
    no.off() 
    $('#overlay').addClass('hidden')
    then()
    }
    
   yes.one('click', () => {off(resolve)})
   no.one('click', () => {off(reject)})
  
   $('#overlay #link').text(url)
   $('#overlay').removeClass('hidden')
  })
 }
 
 jump = (url, target) => {
  if(!target || target == '_self') {
   window.location.href = url;
  } else {
   window.open(url, target)
  }
 }
 
 handle = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  link = e.currentTarget
  
  let url = $(link).attr('href')
  let target = $(link).attr('target')
        let host = location.host

        if ((host && url.indexOf(host) > -1) || !/^https?:/.test(url)){ // relative link
   jump(url, target)
  } else {
   try {
    await confirm(url)
    jump(url, target)
   } catch(e) {/*nope*/}
  }
 }
 
 attach = () => {
  $('#content').on('click','a', handle)
 }
 
 $(attach)
```

```css
#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 display: flex;
}

#confirm-dialog {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 min-height: 7em;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: .5em;
 margin: auto auto;
}

#confirm-dialog h1 { 
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1.5rem; 
 font-style: normal; 
 font-variant: normal; 
 font-weight: 700; 
 line-height: 1.7rem; 
 text-align: center;
 }

#footer {
 position: absolute;
 height: 3em;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 display: flex;
 border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
#link {
 margin-bottom: 3em;
 padding: .5em;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
#footer button {
 width: 10em;
 margin: .2em 1em;
}

.hidden {
 display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay" class="hidden">
 <div id="confirm-dialog">
  <h1>Do you want to navigate to:</h1>
  <div id="link"></div>
  <div id="footer">
   <button id="yes">Yes</button>
   <button id="no">No</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
 This is an <a href="/apple">internal link</a> while this one is <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">external</a> like <a href="http://codeproject.com">this</a> too.
</div>
```

PS: the `window.open` is not working here because it runs sandboxed.

Comment: Thank You ZorgoZ. I was able to find an alternative to my solution. I will post it  shortly

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone who helped me with my question. I was able to figure out by passing in the href to the ok button when the popup appears on the screen. In by button, I pass in the following value in the href: `e.currentTarget.href`. Once I added that, it worked like a charm.

Here is the full code if anyone else would like to use it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),
            host = location.host;

        if (url.indexOf(host) > -1 || url.indexOf('http','https') == -1){
            /* If we find the host name within the URL,
               OR if we do not find http or https, 
               meaning it is a relative internal link
            */
            window.location.href = url;
        } else {

            var m = modal.open({content: "<div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'>
            <h4 class='modal-title'>You are Now Leaving Our Site.</h4>
            <button id='closex' style='margin:8px' type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
            <span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button></div><div class='modal-body'>" 
            + "<p>You are now exiting the NameOfSite web site.  When you exit this 
            site to access a different non-NameOfSite web site, you become subject to the other web site’s privacy 
            policy and practices.  To learn about the other web site’s policy and practices, refer to the privacy 
            policy statement posted on the web site’s home page.<br /><br />Press Ok to Continue
            <br />Press Cancel to Abort</p>" + "<br />" + "<div class='modal-footer'>
            <a id='redirect' class='btn btn-primary' href='" + e.currentTarget.href + "' target='_blank'>Ok</a>
            <button id='close' class='btn btn-default' href='#'>Cancel</button></div></div></div>"});

            if(m == true) {
                return m;
            } 
        }
    });

});
```